# Compress a video using libavcodec / libavformat

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, libavcodec, libavformat

I have written a MS Windows c++ application in Visual Studio that shows a certain animation in OpenGL. I have managed to grab this animation as frames and save these to a mpg file by using libavcodec.

Now I want to compress this video and save it as a mp4 file. I can do this with ffmpeg -i input.mpg -c:v libx264 -qmin 15 -qmax 35 -crf 28 output.mp4 which typically reduces the file size by a factor 10.

However, I would like to achieve the same result by using libavcodec / libavformat directly. Can somebody please show me c++ code that managesthis conversion.

PS
I have very limited experience with libavcodec / libavformat so far. I am learning by the day ...

Comment: Look into `doc/examples` directory, e.g. at https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will study it. However, at first look, I don't find any use of crf, qmin or qmax in that particular example. Can you explain where I can set these parameters ? While opening the output file or in the filter settings ?

Comment: These parameters can be set through `AVCodecContext::qmin`, `AVCodecContext::qmax`, and `X264Context::crf` (accessible through `AVCodecContext::priv_data`). See [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html) and [this](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structX264Context.html).